# Не запускается лицензированный матлаб

Tags: matlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже захожу в папку `activate_matlab` и добавляю файл с лицензией, прохожу эту процедуру, но после все равно эта ошибка вылезает.

Comment: вообще тут несколько вариант почему может быть ошибка
1 - Не удалось подключиться к серверу лицензий. 
2 - Не удалось подключиться к серверу лицензий. В этом случае нужно проверить, доступен ли сервер лицензий, который указан в файле лицензии.
3 - Не удалось подключиться к серверу лицензий. В этом случае нужно проверить, доступен ли сервер лицензий, который указан в файле лицензии.

Comment: как проверить доступен ли сервер лицензий?

Comment: Надо проверить, доступен ли сервер лицензий, который указан в файле лицензии.

Answer (score 0):

Файл с лицензией нужно помещать в папку licenses

Comment: А почему лицензия должна быть в папке `licenses`?